# What might be wrong with this MongoDB update $set query via PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

I am a little stuck with an updating on a collection.

So, I have this query:

```
$coll->update(
            array("_id" => new MongoId($_POST["id"])),
            array("$set" => array(
                "contentType" => htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(trim($_POST["type"]))),
                "contentTitle" => htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(trim($_POST["title"]))),
                "contentBody" => htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(trim($_POST["content"])))
            )),
            true,
            false
        );
```

Please don't bother with the way of validating the $_POST, it's only a test, but it doesn't work. The collection is ok, I have checked that. It doesn't do anything, and when I insert
`var_dump($db->lastError());`
it gives me no errors at all.

Comment: Have you set the query to run in Safe mode? If FALSE (default), the program continues executing without waiting for a database response. If TRUE, the program will wait for the database response and throw a MongoCursorException if the update did not succeed. That may be why your last error is not returning anything. http://us.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.update.php

Comment: The problem is that I don't get bac any expection...

Comment: What is this? -> Mon Feb  6 17:06:49 malformed UTF-8 character sequence at offset 127

Comment: You won't get back any exception if safe mode is not on.

Comment: Ok, I've tried a different way for update, please check it. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have got the solution for the moment.

```
$r = $coll->findOne(
            array(
                "_id" => new MongoId($_POST["id"])
            )
        );
        //
        $r["contentType"] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(trim($_POST["type"])));
        $r["contentTitle"] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(trim($_POST["title"])));
        $r["contentBody"] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(trim($_POST["content"])));
        //
        $coll->save($r);
```

So this one works fine. However I would very much like to find out the previous thingy... =P
If anyone knows why it isn't working feel free to answer! =]

Comment: You mean I should try this?

$coll->update(
 array("_id" => new MongoId($_POST["id"])),
 array("$set" => array(
  "contentType" => htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(trim($_POST["type"]))),
  "contentTitle" => htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(trim($_POST["title"]))),
  "contentBody" => htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(trim($_POST["content"])))
 )),
 array("upsert" => false),
 array("fsync" => true),
 array("safe" => true)
);

Comment: array("upsert" => false,"fsync" => true, "safe" => true) is more appropriate for the last parameter I think

Answer (score 0):

check your apache logs it may be of any help. based on [update](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.update.php) the third parameter is an array. You may want to adhere to that.

Comment: Nope, no apache on this machine... This is a VM only for MongoDB... The webserver is on a different VM... Only this updating sh*t doesn't work (yet).
I have even checked var/log/mongo/mongod.log, nothing unusual there...
And the whole script exits when I give an array("upsert"=>true) instead of the true and false parameters at the end of the update...

Comment: did you check what version of mongodb and pecl extension is used? probably there was some issue with that. you may also set your error handling to `E_ALL`

Comment: check if your php extension version and the mongodb server version are compatible with each other

Comment: I have created this VM on friday and "yum install pecl" so I don't think that would b the problem...

Comment: using the console of MongoDB have you tried finding the document given the value of the `$_POST['id']`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7392/discussion-between-melvin-protacio-and-benqus)

Comment: Ok, I've tried a different way for update, please check it. =)